# If you don't plan to filter anything do you still have to use filter_input vs $_POST?

Tags: php, security

This is kind of a stupid question but if I actually want the raw input, what difference does `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo')` make vs `$_POST['foo']`? It is widely recommended to use the former but it's longer to type.

Comment: See this http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: @StaticVariable I already know that

Comment: you could create an array of rules with `filter_input_array`

Comment: See first contributed note....